# Automatic adjustment to iOS device resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

up to now I have been using a if and else statement to define the size of objects that are displayed on iPhone or iPad, like for example:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        //For Portrait on iPhone
        [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, 320.0f, 44.0)];

    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        //For Landscape on iPhone
        [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, 480.0f, 44.0)];

    }    
} else {
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        //For Portrait on iPad
        [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, 768.0f, 44.0)];

    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        //For Landscape on iPad
        [self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, 1024.0f, 44.0)];

    }      
}
```

But now I want to change it in order to make it a bit more dynamic. I am trying to use the following but there is no luck at all.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);
```

Can anybody please help me on how to implement these two together? It seems that the way I mix them up is the problem. If anybody can give me a template or even a hint for that I will really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you use scale at all for a frame?  That makes no sense as frame values are always in points, not pixels...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're overthinking this. Why not just:

```
[self.navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44.0)];
```

Comment: hi mate, I am trying for hours to implement that but it seems that it works only on iPhone! On iPad I get the values for iphone size, so the navigation bar is small and cannot cover the whole screen. Is there any additional step that I have to do?

Comment: I have used NSLog to test it out and it gives me always the value 320.00